# StaticInjectorError(AppModule) Error while Using angularJS directive in Angular Component

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm trying to upgrade an angularjs directive to use it my angular component.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@Directive({
    selector:'[analyticsEvent]'
})

export class MyDirective extends UpgradeComponent {
@Input('analyticsEvent') appHighlight: string;
count = 1;
constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    super('analyticsEvent', elementRef, injector);
}

@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
clickEvent(event) {
    this.count++
    console.log('this.count++')
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

its throwing the below error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[$injector]:
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[$injector]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for $injector!
```

what's the issue here ?

Comment: Please give the code of `UpgradeComponent`.

Comment: thats imported from angular [UpgradeComponent](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#using-angularjs-component-directives-from-angular-code)

Comment: My bad, didn't know about this component. I'm not sure this is the right way to import it though ... You usually import from `@angular/XXX`, not `@angular/XXX/YYY/ZZZ`